# How can I replace commas with & in the following string using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I have a string like this:

```
my $string = 'Respect,13,201,7,0,0,2,3.70,4,1.01,Responsibility,13,177,29,1,1,2,3.58,4,1.04,Flexibility,13,180,27,0,0,3,3.59,4,1.05,Collaboration,13,194,13,0,0,3,3.65,4,1.04,Reflection,13,187,19,1,0,3,3.62,4,1.05,Commitmentto Learning,13,183,24,0,0,3,3.61,4,1.05,Beliefin Educator Efficacy,13,177,13,0,0,20,3.35,4,1.42,SocialIntelligence,13,184,22,1,0,3,3.61,4,1.05';
```

How can I write a pattern to be used with `s///` to replace each comma (`,`) just before the `\w+` (e.g., `Responsibility, Flexibility, Collaboration ...` ) with an ampersand (`&`)'?

Comment: Do you to replace by `$` (as said in title) or `&` (as said in text)?

Comment: I assume there's an implied `"...but not replace commas in front of..."`. Why don't you make it official?

Comment: I'm confused. All commas are just before `\w+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a lookahead assertion, like this:

```
s/,(?=[a-z]+)/&/gi
```

You should replace the `[a-z]+` part with a more specific pattern based on your input.

Comment: In `sed` or another tool without lookahead assertions you would just capture the lookahead and put it back:  `sed -e 's/,\([a-zA-Z]\)/\&\1/g'`.  The `&` has to be escaped because as a substitution it inserts the entire matched string.

Answer (score 2):

To replace all commas followed by `\w+` (as you asked), I recommend

```
s/,(?=\w)/&/g
```

Since all commas are followed by `\w+`, the above can be simplified to

```
s/,/&/g
```

If your actual intent is to only replace the commas that are followed by letters, you want

```
s/,(?=\pL)/&/g
```